IntersectionObserver with Preact lists
I have a preact application where I am displaying a list of items which are obtained from a server call. I am using functional components.
I need to make additional server calls when an item in the list is visible to the user, therefore I am looking at the IntersectionObserver.
Creating the IntersectionObserver
I can create the observer as follows (currently it just logs a console message when the item element comes into view).
const intersectionCallback = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[], observer: IntersectionObserver) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            console.log('IN OBSERVER', entry.target);
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);  // stop observing this item
        }
    });
}

const options = {
    root: document.getElementById('my-list-element-id'), 
    rootMargin: '0px',                              
    threshold: 0,                                   
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback, options);

Observing items
Items can be observed using something like the following
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('list-view-row-element');
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    observer.observe(elements[i]);
}

My list items are being rendered in a function inside my Function Component, they are not components themselves.
ISSUE
The issue I have is how/when to mark the rows as being observed.
In all the examples I have seen the HTML contains all the elements to observe, so "querySelectorAll" will find them as soon as the page is rendered.
In my example, the list rows will not be in the HTML until the server call has completed.
How do I know when the list rows have been added to the HTML in order to observe them?

You shouldn't be using document.querySelector (or other DOM selectors) w/ (p)react, it's not the way you're meant to be writing components.
Generally, refs and useEffect is the answer:
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'preact/hooks';

function MyListEntry() {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current !== null) {
            observer.observe(ref.current);
        }
        return () => observer.unobserve(ref.current);
    }, []);

    return <list-view-row-element ref={ref}>...</list-view-row-element>;
}


I did look at refs, unfortunately my list item rows are not Functional Components, therefore i can not use hooks.  I get the error
"React Hook "useRef" is called in function "renderRow" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. "
I might have to look at refactoring our code.
Thank you for the comment

In Preact, you can use hooks in class components, that error is not from us. I'm not sure I would necessarily recommend it, but you absolutely can do it.

You also don't need hooks to work with refs, they'll work just fine with class components too. Checkout the docs

I have refactored my code so that my list item rows are now components (they were just functions before) and now i can use "useEffect" and "refs" just like you said in this answer and this works perfectly.  Thank you
